# My Function Call Doesn't Work Inside A echo

Tags: javascript, php

Here is my php code:

```
<div class="box-body" id="chosen-tags">
<?php
$cnt = 1;
for($cnt=1;$cnt<=20;$cnt++){
    echo "<a id='abcd$cnt' style='float:left;'>abcd".$cnt."&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>";
}
?>
</div>


<div class="box-body" id="tags-toggle-content" style="display: none">
<?php
$cnt = 1;
for($cnt=1;$cnt<=20;$cnt++){
    $idd = "abcd".$cnt; 
    echo "<a id='abc$cnt' style='float:left' onclick='add_tagss($idd)'>abc".$cnt."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>";
}
?>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggle_visibility(id) 
    {
       var f = document.getElementById(id)
       if(f.style.display == 'block')
          f.style.display = 'none';
       else
          f.style.display = 'block';
    }

    function add_tagss()
    {
      var f = document.getElementById("id");
      f.style.display = 'none';

    }

    </script>
```

I really think that my error is on my function call inside a echo. Is there any rule on how to execute a function call inside a echo such as the proper usage of single and double quote.

Comment: you have issue on this line ` echo "<a id='abc$cnt' style='float:left' onclick='add_tagss($idd)'>abc".$cnt."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>";`

Answer (score 2):

You are messing up with single and double quotes.

Whenever you think you are messing up with javascript and PHP, break the string.

Its not mandatory to echo a string within double quotes at one go.

You can do several concatenations to achieve the same.

Best practice while writing javascript code in PHP is:

1) View source code to find out whether javascript code is properly coded. Of course, view source will not display AJAX generated code. Use `Firefox's Inspect Element` in this case.

2) Check if parameters of javascript functions are passed properly with single quotes.

3) In Firefox, check in `console` tab if PHP written javascript code is generating some errors.

4) In javascript function, use `console.log()` to check if proper variable is passed.

**Some modifications:**

Change

```
echo "<a id='abc$cnt' style='float:left' onclick='add_tagss($idd)'>abc".$cnt."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>";
```

To:

```
echo "<a id='".$idd."' style='float:left'" .  "onclick=add_tagss('".$idd."')>abc".$cnt."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>";
```

And in function you are not receiving any parameter:

Change it to:

```
function add_tagss(id)
    {
      var f = document.getElementById(id);
      f.style.display = 'none';

    }
```

Comment: bro! Your a genius. Thank you very much. You save me there!

Comment: @OwsMGTan, you are welcome.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with putting it all in one string, the real problem is that the string value is not quoted so javascript will see it as an (undefined...) variable. The rest is just personal preferences and / or improving readability.

Comment: Yes @jeroen, I agree, there is nothing wrong in putting all in one string. I have said it is not mandatory, but, it is correct. The user is new and I simplified it for his comfort. Again, thanks for taking interest.

Answer (score -1):

you are calling pa parameterised function but its defination doesn't have the parameter, look for this add_tagss('param');

`call add_tagss(".$idd."); instead onclick='add_tagss($idd)'` and definition should accept parameter. Hope this might help you.

Comment: Tnx bro. but it's still not working. But there's no syntax error in the following code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, in second for lop - where you add function call in anchor tag - try below script - it will successfully call function :

```
for($cnt=1;$cnt<=20;$cnt++)
{
    $idd = "abcd".$cnt;
    echo "<a href='#' id='abc$cnt' style='float:left;' onclick='add_tagss(\"".$idd."\")'>abc".$cnt."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>";

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="box-body" id="chosen-tags">
    <?php
    $cnt = 1;
    for($cnt=1;$cnt<=20;$cnt++)
    {
        echo "<a id='abcd$cnt' style='float:left;'>abcd".$cnt."&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>";
    }
    ?>
</div>
<hr />

<div class="box-body" id="tags-toggle-content" style="display: block">
    <?php
    $cnt = 1;
    for($cnt=1;$cnt<=20;$cnt++)
    {
        $idd = "abcd".$cnt;


        echo "<a id='abcd$cnt' style='float:left' onclick='add_tagss(\"$idd\")'>abc".$cnt."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>";

    }
    ?>


</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggle_visibility(id)
    {
        var f = document.getElementById(id)
        if(f.style.display == 'block')
            f.style.display = 'none';
        else
            f.style.display = 'block';
    }

    function add_tagss(idd)
    {

        var f = document.getElementById(idd);
        f.style.display = 'none';

    }

</script>
```